# jmock simplest case doesn't work

Tags: java, jmock

That's my JMock test:

```
@Test
public void testRunModuleOK() {
    App instance = getInstanceApp(window,logger);
    Mockery context = new JUnit4Mockery();
    final Modulable m = context.mock(Modulable.class);

    context.checking(new Expectations() {{
        oneOf(m).init(logger);
        oneOf(m).start();
    }});

    instance.runModule(m);

}
```

And that's runModule:

```
void runModule(Modulable module) {
    if(module == null) 
        throw new NullPointerException("Module is null");
    module.init(mainLogger);
    runningModules.add(module);
    module.start();
}
```

I want my test to make sure that init() and start() is always called once.
Unfortunately, when I comment out module.init and module.start in runModule, test still passes. I used println to make sure the code and the test is called.
Strangely, when I call init (or start) twice, I get failure as expected. Also, when I comment out 'oneOf...' from expectations, I also get failure.
Why does the test passes if module.init and / or module.start is not called in runModule?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the verify step that tells JMock that your test is finished and it should close off any outstanding checks.  Call `assertIsSatisfied()` on your mock context.

Alternatively, switch from using `Mockery context = new JUnit4Mockery();` to using `@Rule public JUnitRuleMockery context = new JUnitRuleMockery();`.  This will cut out some of that sort of boilerplate for you.

Comment: Thanks. I used this site: http://jmock.org/getting-started.html tab Jmock4. Seems like a error for me.

Comment: Not an error.  Your test is not using the `JUnit4RuleMockey` `@Rule` which does `assertIsSatisfied()` for you.  If you look at the "Other" set of examples in the getting-started page, you'll see the explanation just before "Here is the complete test.".